# C++ type's destructor not called in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, destructor, qt5

I create a Sailfish app (using latest Sailfish SDK). I have a problem with exposing a C++ object to QML. It inherits QSettings,

```
class Settings : public QSettings
{
    Q_OBJECT
    /**/
public:
    explicit Settings() : QSettings("Marcin Mielniczuk", "BigText") {}
    ~Settings() { qDebug() << "Dying"; }

    /**/
};
```

I noticed that the destructor isn't called at all. (there's not destructor output)

I create the object like that:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0
import BigText 1.0
import "pages"

ApplicationWindow
{
    initialPage: MainPage { }
    Settings {id: settings}
}
```

My main.cpp is:

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QGuiApplication> app(Sailfish::createApplication(argc, argv));

    qmlRegisterType<Settings>("BigText", 1, 0, "Settings");

    QScopedPointer<QQuickView> view(Sailfish::createView("main.qml"));

    Sailfish::showView(view.data());

    return app->exec();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

/edit: Text not being printed isn't an actual problem - it's just an indicator of the problem. The QSettings sycing in the destructor doesn't work too.

EDIT2: Please note, that ApplicationWindow in I'm using Sailfish Silica, not QtQuick.Controls, and the window is shown ok. These components must be a somewhat different to the stock qt quick components.

Comment: Is QSettings's destructor virtual?

Comment: Change qDebug to std::cout, i think, qDebug could be using event loop...

Comment: No success, but it wouldn't fix the problem anyway - QSettings syncing in desctructor doesn't work as well... (even without explicit destructor)

Comment: doctorlove: Yes, QSettings inherits from QObject, whose destructor is virtual.

Comment: Well, nothing is wrong indeed. Look at my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with my code. It's something with the SDK. Debugging shows

```
ASSERT: "QThread::currentThread() == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread()" in file debugger/qqmldebugserver.cpp, line 576
```

Then the program is aborted and therefore destructor not called.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your logic. Here is a simplified version of it. I can run it locally, and consistently get a *Dying* message on output every time the window is closed and the application terminates.

If you cannot figure it out, I suggest transforming this code into what you're doing until it fails.

By the way, this is surely just a snippet of something larger you're doing, but at least as far as the example goes, these scoped pointers aren't doing much.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import BigText 1.0

Item {
    width: 300; height: 300
    Settings {id: settings}
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
class Settings : public QSettings
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    Settings() : QSettings("Marcin Mielniczuk", "BigText") {}
    ~Settings() { qDebug() << "Dying"; }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QGuiApplication> app(new QGuiApplication(argc, argv));
    qmlRegisterType<Settings>("BigText", 1, 0, "Settings");
    QScopedPointer<QQuickView> view(new QQuickView());
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view->show();
    return app->exec();
}
```

Comment: It did work when I did like that. But as soon as I changed Item to ApplicationWindow it stopped working...

Comment: It won't ever work because you can't use a `QQuickView` with `ApplicationWindow`. It's not even loading the main component.

Comment: In the Sailfish SDK there's Qt 5.0.2 (which is, as written in the release notes "almost 5.1"). The rest of the app works alright. The engine is created by Sailfish::create. It's defined like here: https://github.com/owncloud/News-Qt-App/blob/master/sailfishapplication/sailfishapplication.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put and id yo tour ApplicationWindow and explicity use the destroy() method at some time and see what happens.

Comment: ApplicationWindow is to be undestructible. I can manually destroy Settings and it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `QQuickView` with an `ApplicationWindow` class. Not only is your destructor not called, your constructor isn't *either*, because the loading doesn't ever succeed.

The code below works fine under Qt 5.1.1. Tested on both OS X 10.8 and Windows 7.

**main.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.pro**

```
QT       += core gui qml quick
TARGET = qml-appwin-end-18597527
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
OTHER_FILES += main.qml
RESOURCES += main.qrc
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QDebug>

class Settings : public QSettings
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    Settings() : QSettings("Marcin Mielniczuk", "BigText") {}
    ~Settings() { qDebug() << "Dying"; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<Settings>("BigText", 1, 0, "Settings");
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import BigText 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 300
    Settings {id: settings}
}
```

Comment: It seems that ApplicationWindow is Sailfish Silica is somewhat different, as it works ok apart from destroing child objects. Loading the window succeeds